# Python :My generator is returning the passed list instead of a filtered output

Tags: python

The code filters the list in such a way that it only returns me the first three values of the list. I tried another generator as well to print only the even numbers but i'm getting the same problem i.e. the whole list is being printed.

```
def take(count, iterable):

    counter = 0
    for item in iterable:
        if counter==count:
            return
        count+=1
        yield item



def run_take():
    items = [2,6,5,23,1,4,6,7]

    for item in take(3,items):
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_take()
```

This should print 2,6,5 but rather prints the  full list. Why???

EDIT : Sorry, i made a very silly error. The counter variable was to be incremented.

Comment: `counter += 1` not `count += 1`

Comment: `for i in range(count):
        yield iterable[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were incrementing `count` while you should have been incrementing `counter`

```
def take(count, iterable):

    counter = 0
    for item in iterable:
        if counter==count:
            return
        counter+=1
        yield item



def run_take():
    items = [2,6,5,23,1,4,6,7]

    for item in take(3,items):
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_take()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there's a logical error in your code. In your `take` function, you want to increment `counter` instead of `count`.

```
def take(count, iterable):
    counter = 0
    for item in iterable:
        if counter == count:
            return
        counter += 1
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Increment Counter my friend. You've incremented the count variable instead